# Is "enroute" an acceptable variant of "en route"?

Tags: orthography, spacing, french, variants, foreign-phrases

Is "enroute" (without the space) an acceptable variant of "en route"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don’t think so.  That would be like spelling *et cetera* as **etcetera* without a space.  It is not like *ensemble* either, which was one word to start with.

The OED has **lots** of French phrases of the form *en XXX* that have been borrowed into English, and I don’t see a single one of them that collapses its spacing:

- *en attendant*
- *en avant*
- *en axe*
- *en barbette*
- *en beau*
- *en bloc*
- *en brosse*
- *en cabochon*
- *en casserole*
- *en cœur*
- *en clair*
- *en coquille*
- *en déshabillé*
- *en évidence*
- *en face*
- *en famille*
- *en fête*
- *en garçon*
- *en grande tenue*
- *en grand seigneur*
- *en gros*
- *en l’air*
- *en masse*
- *en noir*
- *en pantoufles*
- *en passant*
- *en pension*
- *en permanence*
- *en plein*
- *en pointe(s*
- *en poste*
- *en prince*
- *en principe*
- *en prise*
- *en rapport*
- *en regard*
- *en règle*
- *en retraite*
- *en revanche*
- *en route*
- *en secondes noces*
- *en suite*
- *en tout cas*
- *en train*
- *en ventre sa mère*
- *en ville*

We don’t do that with the *à la XXX* phrases, either:

- *à contre-cœur*
- *à deux*
- *à fond*
- *à gogo*
- *à la bonne heure*
- *à la carte*
- *à la mode*
- *à la page*
- *à merveille*
- *à terre*
- *à tort et à travers*
- *à trois*

Sono, I don’t think you canrun it alltogether. :)

Comment: Awesome examples! Think this erases all doubt.

Answer (score 4):

*Enroute* is certainly acceptable, as an equivalent to *en route* or *en-route*, when used as a term of art in aviation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En-route_chart

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to you and your readers then that settles it.

But, I wouldn't. "En" and "route" are two separate words in French. In English you wouldn't write onroute, just as you shouldn't write alot.

Comment: But you can say 'cannot'! Though you cannot say 'willnot'.